# Changing background-color with onclick-function

Tags: html, css, onclick

I want to change the background color of a class by clicking on a class. The code that I tried doesn't work. Thank you in advance

HTML:

```
<a href="#!" onclick="message()" onclick="message()" class="changeBack"> SEND ME A MESSAGE </a>
```

CSS:

```
.changeBack {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function message() {

        var background = document.getElementsByClassName("changeBack").style.backgroundColor;
            if (background == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)") {
                 background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
        } else {
        background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is your code.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('box');
    if (x.style.backgroundColor === 'red') {
        x.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    } else {
        x.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

```css
#box{
background-color:red;
padding:1rem;
width : 50%;
height:150px;
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my file. I already another onclick-function (see edit), or is this not possible? And it has to contain a if/else-statement because it's changing everytime you click on the class. edit: I deleted the message() and then it does work, but if I combine them together, it doesn''t.

Comment: It does work now thank you!

Comment: I edit my snippet to be toggle script you can run it now it's changing everytime.